# Polygons.contains() not working (Polygon has area and is_valid = True)

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I am trying to get a state out of an .shp file given Lat and Lon:

I have loaded the files both for the .shp (map) and .csv (Lat Lon values)

I  managed to return a map with all the dots inside:

```
    geometry = [Point (xy) for xy in zip(Atrain["lon"],Atrain["lat"])]
    geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = geometry)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = ((15,15)))
    shp_br.plot(ax =ax)
    geo_df.plot(ax = ax,color = "red")
```

resulting in:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFGwG.png

(sorry, not enough reputation to post image, new to site)

but then, my loop results in false for a value that should be there:

```
    pt = Point(-10, -50)
    s = 0
    for i in shp_br["geometry"]:
        if i.contains(pt):
            print(shp_br["NM_ESTADO"][s])
        s +=1
```

Any clues of what might be causing this?
Thanks!

Comment: I just checked and the areas of the polygons matches with the real measures of the states areas

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, my point isn`t supposed to be there because i've written it in a format (Lat, Lon) when it should be (Lon, Lat)